# sectionally/piecewise continuous functions

Tags: analysis

Assume
$f$
and
$g$
are two piecewise continuous functions on an interval
$(
a
,
b
)$
containing the point
$t_0$
. Assume further that
$f$
has a jump discontinuity at
$t_0$
while
$g$
is
continuous at
$t_0$
.How can i verify that the jump in the product
$fg$
at
$t_0$
is given by
“the jump in
$f$
at
$t_0$
”
×
$g
(
t_0
)$
?

Answer (score 1):

You can take the the two one-sided limits of $fg$, getting $\displaystyle \lim_{x \to t_0^+} f(x)g(x) - \displaystyle \lim_{x \to t_0^-} f(x)g(x)$.